# set bones in edit mode to object mode position

Tags: edit-mode, bones, object-mode

Somehow my bones have a differed position in edit mode and object mode. I have deleted all timeline transformations and rotations of the bones (pose mode). Also there is no mesh parented to the bones. I have tried Alt+r in pose mode, but that does not give the same position as in edit mode.

How can I set the bones in edit mode to the position in object mode?

Nothing in pose mode:
[image: nothing in pose mode]

Object mode position:
[image: object mode position]

Edit mode position:
(note his right shoulder joint is clearly not the same positions and more bones are wrong)
[image: Edit mode position]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured out how to set the object mode to *edit mode*.
<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> for *rotation*
<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> for *translation*
<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for *scale*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).